# Compute $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(a^kb_0 +a^{k-1}b_1 +\cdots+b_k)$ if $|a|<1$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k $ converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k $ converges absolutely and has the sum $b$. Suppose $a \in\mathbb R$ with $|a|<1$. What is the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(a^kb_0 +a^{k-1}b_1 +a^{k-2}b_2 +...+b_k)$?

Comment: Are you sure that the expression ends with $b_k$ where $k$ is the dummy index over which the sum is done??

Comment: I suspect the question is to evaluate $\lim_{k\to \infty} (a^kb_0 + a^{k-1}b_1 + a^{k-2}b_2 + \cdots + b_{k-1}a + b_k)$.

Comment: @Jeff See edited question.

Comment: OP: Any personal input?

Answer (score 2):

It's $\frac{b}{1-a}$. Since the series $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty a^k$ and $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty b_k$ converge absolutely, the Cauchy product of the two series converges to $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty a^k\cdot \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty b_k = \frac{1}{1-a}\cdot b = \frac{b}{1-a}$. The Cauchy product is

$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \sum_{j = 0}^k a^{k-j} b_j = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (a^kb_0 + a^{k-1}b_1 + \cdots + b_k)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is the *Cauchy product of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ and  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$. As both series converge absolutely, their Cauchy product converge to the product of each sum, $b\cdot\dfrac1{1-a}$.